# Cómo enlazar un div que está en otro archivo html?

Tags: html, html5

En un archivo html tengo una etiqueta header en el cual existe un menú donde en las etiquetas a mediante el href enlazo al id del div que deseo y otra etiqueta main donde cree varios div y funciona perfectamente cuando en el atributo href de la etiqueta a llamo al id del div deseado; mi problema es cuando estoy en otro archivo html no tengo idea de como enlazar al div de la primer pag.html en el href de la etiqueta a del menú que esta página muestra.

He intentado  `<a href="index.html/#et-ia">ingeniero / arquitecto</a></li>` pero cuando lo trato de ejecutar en el buscador se me indica que no se puede acceder al archivo, de igual manera intente poniendo
`<a href="/HTML/index.html/#et-ia">`y `<a href="../HTML/index.html/#et-ia">`(al comienzo puse 2 puntos porque para enlazar una imagen solo pude acceder al archivo poniendo eso al inicio del path), talvez tienen alguna opción para solucionar este problema

Comment: La estructura que usas en el href se usa para apuntar a un enlace (anchor `<a>`) en el otro documento, no a un div.

Comment: en varias páginas indican que si se puede apuntar a una sección en específico para no tener que ver todo el contenido previo

Comment: Y cómo se marca una sección en un documento HTML? No están hablando del DOM, están hablando de cómo lo estructuran para navegarlo. Para eso se usan anchors (`<a>` sin href -o con href a sí mismos-) con un id (o name? esa parte no la recuerdo 100%) que permite apuntarles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Miren en el atributo href omití el "/" antes del "#" y ya me dirigió al div que se encuentra en el otro archivo html.

`<a href="../HTML/index.html#et-ia">`

espero que esto también pueda ayudar a otras personas que talvez tengan la misma inquietud que tuve al principio y gracias por el aporte de los demás usuarios.

Comment: Recuerda marcar como aceptada la respuesta que resuelve el problema

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta, gran hallazgo! Soy oficialmente un dinosaurio :P

Answer (score 0):

Con HTML plano, le apuntas siempre a anchors (etiquetas `<a>`), que su función es ofrecer un enlace para permitir la navegación entre documentos HTML. No siempre deben tener un hipervínculo a otro recurso.

La clave es recordar que los HTML son **documentos** creados siguiendo un estándar. Las etiquetas que creamos en el DOM le dan sentido semántico o proveen herramientas para pintar el documento de alguna forma, pero es un documento.

Caso de ejemplo: una página cualquiera como... https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments

Esta página tiene varias secciones (como documento, semánticamente, no en el DOM). Subtítulos, diríamos.

Esta sección que elegí al azar, tiene un `#` junto al título y, si haces hover...

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

verás un enlace a ese anchor (`https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments#_manually-specify-an-interpreter`)

Al revisar ese documento, se ve que ese anchor está definido así:

```
<a class="hash-link transparent" href="#_manually-specify-an-interpreter">#</a>
```

Así, si compartes ese enlace, el navegador se *ancla* en ese anchor y te pinta la página enfocado en esa parte del contenido.

Resumen, no le apunta a un div sino a anchors. Esto existe hace un rato ya en HTML. Para hacer lo que buscas, apuntándole a un div, posiblemente se requiera enviar parámetros en la URL y que código JS interprete los parámetros de la URL, busque el div con ese id y desplace la página

Algo como que le envíes `http://URL?pageFocus=blablatab` y tu código JS valide onLoad, use los parámetros con los que se cargó la página y haga algo como

```
document.getElementById('blablatab').focus();
```